# phaser input delay when touch quickly

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I am using phaser v2.5.0 on Samsung s5 device
which the game is inside the iframe

when I keep touch the canvas(using many fingers at the same time) quickly,
the input down /input up event are sent very very slow
its take about 15second to send all touch event touched within 5sec

how can I clear the touch event cache?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Can you please share u'r code or example of your code and let us see what's wrong?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8cmj6I8cOZ4YUx0azdXbkYtMHc/view?usp=sharing
here is the chrome timeline log,
we have found that every touch event's "waiting for main thread time" is very long,so phaser can not received any click event on time.
and its mostly happen to phaser take many time to process every frame